# Oracle Blob object ingestion into Snowflake

Tags: oracle, blob, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I'm aware that Snowflake doesn't really have an Oracle Blob equivalent, but i'm just curious how are other out there addressing the need for having Blob data from Oracle in their data-warehouse? Specifically where the general 16MB limit on VARCHAR and 8MB limit on Binary is not enough.

Comment: It depends on how you are using it. You're not running analytical queries on blobs right? I suggest putting the blob's in actual blob storage (not in a database) with a filename that reflects the key of the table.

Comment: not Oracle Blob, but we had PostgreSQL BYTEA data that I loaded in as a BASE64 encoded string, and then  decoded inside a Javascript UDF (it was encoded data, so I just unpacked it to a JSON object) and then it was wonderful. But it was nowhere near the limits... might have topped out in the 2MB range.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that's the only solution i could think of too. Thanks.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim yup that what we do for anything we know wont hit the limit, but we've finally come across one that did

Comment: I mean it's not even a workaround. How are the blobs actually being used? It's not like you want to run a relational query that depends on some sub component of the blob. Usually blobs are things like Word documents and pictures. So you have a database record that belongs and lives in a database and gets all that ACID good stuff. And you have a blob that lives in separate blob storage and you have a front end app that puts the two together. What you _don't_ have is any requirement for the blob to be covered by ACID, or to be involved in a SELECT query.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you're not wrong, it just means additional complexity versus straight 1 for 1 ingestion. I think we might end up going with this option.

Answer (score 0):

These are some examples I have come across for "Specifically where the general 16MB limit on VARCHAR and 8MB limit on Binary is not enough"

1. [Storing ore that 16mb data in Snowflake](https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/question/0D50Z00008h9JVPSA2/storing-more-than-16-mb-data-in-snowflake) - Variant 16mb of compressed data
2. [How To Load Data Into Snowflake – Snowflake Data Load Best Practices](https://www.doyouevendata.com/2018/12/21/how-to-load-data-into-snowflake-snowflake-data-load-best-practices/) 
   -  Using a Snowflake stage is a great way plan the upload

Comment: The migration guide also recommends BINARY as mapped data type in the guide: https://resources.snowflake.com/migration-guides/migrating-oracle-database-to-snowflake-reference-manual perhaps that might lead to some more information.